# compiler talking with another compiler by xml

Tags: xml, compiler-construction

My thesis is (XML representation and validation for a context-free grammar).
I need to prove we can using XML between Compilers .
can anyone told me can we make two compilers talking together by XML?

Comment: Of course you can use XML - any AST can be represented in this poor man's substitute for S-expressions. But why do you want to do such a weird thing? Why would not you use a proper AST/IR representation instead?

Comment: Why would you choose that as your thesis if you don't have any idea how to prove it?

Comment: i have problem with my topic,i represent a CFG production roles inside XML document and especially LL(1),then building a schema or dtd to recognize and validate is to see is it LL(1) or not,the problem is what is the benefit of these representation and validation.

Comment: Please slow down a bit. CFG, LL(1), whatever - how exactly all this stuff is related to XML? What exactly are you using XML for, what is the reason for such a choice, and what have you tried already?

Comment: i think the reason is maybe using CFG & xml between compilers.is this useful?